# openbsd carp with multiple external vip's

Tags: openbsd, carp

Is there any way to setup multiple carp vip's without creating a separate hostname.if file for each address?

Our colo has provided us with a /25 external network. Three addresses from this range are required for the colo gateway and my redundant firewalls. I would like the rest of the addresses to be vip's shared by the firewalls.

I can easily create a script to help write the 123 hostname.if files... It just seems like there should be a better way to summarize this info.

Would it be better to ask the colo to route all my traffic to one vip? I am not sure if they will do this.

Comment: So you want 123 IP address on a carp interface, right?

Comment: If possible yes. Either that or it seems that I need 123 carp interfaces. I have read that I can use aliases for this. I am not sure if there is a downside to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, aliases seems the proper way to go.

Like this:

```
 (the first line as it used to be, then)
 inet alias 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.128
 inet alias 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.128
 inet alias 10.1.1.3 255.255.255.128
 .
 .
 .
 inet alias 10.1.1.123 255.255.255.128
```